# Why a function call in Doctrine's proxy object points to parent object instead of inherited child object?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have created an inherited document class, see the code below. The documents persists fine but when fetching the document and trying to call the children's function, I will get an error **Call to undefined method Proxies__CG__\Acme\ProductBundle\Document\ProductBase::getPriceDefinition()** even the child document has getPriceDefinition() function. The proxy points also to the ProductBase, not SimpleProduct.

The parent class, ProductBase.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ProductBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * @MongoDB\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 * @MongoDB\DiscriminatorField(fieldName="type")
 * @MongoDB\DiscriminatorMap({"simple"="SimpleProduct"})
 */
abstract class ProductBase
{   
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id;
     */
    protected $_id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    public $comment;
}
```

The child class, SimpleProduct.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ProductBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class SimpleProduct extends ProductBase
{

    /**
     * @var PriceDefinition
     * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="PriceDefinition") 
     */
    protected $priceDefinition;

    public function getPriceDefinition() {
        return $this->priceDefinition;
    }
}
```

Calling code (only partial):

```
$product = $this->dm->getRepository('AcmeProductBundle:Product')->findOneBy(array('_id' => $productId));
$priceDefinition = $product->getPriceDefinition(); // The error is thrown here
```

Finally the document in the database (that is persisted with the above documents correctly).

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5006d7b76803fa9403000007"),
  "priceDefinition": {
     "referenceValue": 1000000,
     "currency": "iso: EUR",
     "taxBehavior": "fi_vat_a",
     "isGrossPrice": false
  },
  "type": "simple"
}
```

In general this somehow seems that Doctrine would not recognize that the returned object is a subclass. But - if I for example change the database type value to something else than "simple" (for example "not-simple") that does not match the DiscriminatorMap, the Doctrine says "Notice: Undefined index: not-simple (...)".

And what the strangest, as soon as I add getPriceDefinition() in the parent class (ProductBase), it gets called properly and without errors.

Uhh... that was a long question. Anyhow, I am just unable to find out what's the problem here. Is it my getRepository('AcmeProductBundle:Product') call, or my inheritance definitions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `ProductBase` is abstract, is there any reason you're not annotating it as a [MappedSuperclass](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#mappedsuperclass)? ODM is constructing a proxy that extends ProductBase (it does so between your `findOneBy()` call and attempting to call `getPriceDefinition()`), which doesn't make sense in practice. Proxy objects are meant to be used interchangeably with the mapped class -- in this case, the proxy is extending an abstract class which should never exist on its own. Even so, it seems like this odd mapping is causing a bug in the discriminator logic, as that type field should cause `SimpleProduct` to be used.

Also, changing the database value of the `type` field to `not-simple` should not cause the code to elicit a PHP notice. We should be throwing an exception instead.

Would you mind opening separate issues for both of these bugs in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm)? If you're feeling up to it, failing test cases would be welcome as well.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I will open the issues as soon as possible and keep this question/answer also updated. Thanks!

Comment: Finally - after half a year - I opened the issues and added test cases: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/562 for the abstract class issue, https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/563 for missing Exception.